# C Putting code in one liner

Tags: c

I'm learning C and this is probably the most stupid question ever but here it goes!

My code:

```
char tmp = *x++;
char *g = &tmp;
```

Can I do this line of code in a one liner? With something like:

```
char *g = &(*x++);
```

---

More info:

```
char *x = "1234";
//Turn each 'number' to a int
while(*x != '\0'){
    char tmp = *x++;
    char *x = &tmp;
    int t = atoi(x);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean x? Because its declared but this code is just a small piece

Comment: @C.B: How is that relevant? In the initializer of `char *x = &(*x++);`, `x` is in scope. The problem is that `x` has not been initialized or assigned, not that it is not accessible.

Comment: One *line*, yes... one statement, no.

Comment: You can, but please don't (me and all the other people who have to maintain this crap beg you)

Comment: Please do not even start on getting into the habit of writing code that is difficult to read. `char tmp = *x++;` is terrible and you want to make things worse. Just do not do it

Comment: @herohuyongtoas because I need the first 4 chars as int and then the code multiplies. So I thought maybe there is a one line thing to use ;)

Comment: In my opinion this line `char tmp = *x++;` should be two lines

Comment: @EdHeal it isn't that hard to read (my opinion) but then again this isn't the question

Comment: @MouNtant - It is hard to read. It does not make any sense that you need to reduce the lines of code - for what. Something wrong with the keyboard?

Comment: @EdHeal Lately i have been playing with bits alot and I do not feel this is very hard to read but then again it is my opinion and I will leave it like this

Comment: @MouNtant - Come back in a few weeks time with your own code littered with expressions like that. You then are trying to figure out the expressions without gaining the narrative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `x` is a pointer to `char` (and points to an existing object), then the declaration `char *g = &(*x++);` is allowed in standard C and has defined behavior.

The result of the `*` operator is an lvalue, per C 2011 6.5.3.2 4, so its address may be taken with `&`.

In detail:

- `x++` increments `x` and produces the original value of `x`. (Note: Incrementing a pointer requires that the pointer point to an object. It does not require that it be an array element or that there be another object after it; you are allowed to increment to point one past an object, as long as you do not then dereference a pointer to a non-existent object.)
- `*x++` dereferences the pointer (the original value of `x`). The result is an lvalue.
- `&(*x++)` takes the address of the lvalue, which is the original value of `x`.
- Then this value is used to initialize `g`.

Additionally, C 2011 6.5.3.2 3 specifies that the combination of `&` and `*` cancel, except that the result is not an lvalue and the usual constraints apply, so the `&` and `*` operations are not actually evaluated. Thus, this statement is the same as `char *g = x++;`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - But why on Earth write such code that requires digging around. Please feel sorry for people tring to maintain/debug this sort of code

Comment: @EdHeal: (a) That is not the question. (b) Sometimes complicated code arises inadvertently, such as a result of preprocessor macros intended to provide other functions. It is therefore necessary that good programmers understand these things, and it is entirely reasonable to ask questions about them. (c) If you think this is complicated code, you should never see some of the things I have seen over the decades.

Comment: To add extra to Eric comment. My first statement was I am learning

Comment: @EricPostpischil - I put it as a comment. The reason being is that writing code that is unduly complicate does not serve any purpose. It makes it difficult to read, difficult to maintain and also subject to misunderstandings. Better break such code up a little.

Comment: @EdHeal I sure see your point for maintability but then again I'm learning C so this also has alot to do with this question. I will take your feedback with me and use it. Thank you

Comment: @MouNtant - As you are learning just try to write simple code. Even if you need to type in a couple extra lines of code but it means that it is readable and easier to understand it will pay dividends in the future. Lt the compiler do its job and do the optimisation.

Comment: @MouNtant - I personally think that code should read like a book. No fiddly bits but you can just scan it and get the story. Helps with maintenance and debugging especially if you did not write it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a hint: Are you aware that you are shadowing the outer x variable?

What you are currently doing is:

```
char *x = "1234"; //declare c style string
while(*x != '\0'){ //for the conditional the "outer" x will be used for comparsion
    char tmp = *x++; //increment x to point to whatever comes sizint atoi (const char * str);eof(char) bytes afterwards; dereference what x previously pointed to (postfix ++) and save it in local char tmp
    char *x = &tmp; //take adress of the local char and save its adress in a new local/inner char*
    int t = atoi(x); //call atoi on the inner x
```

Although this may work it may be confusing style to shadow variables like this. (Confusing for other developers especially)

Also take a look at the signature of atoi:

```
int atoi (const char * str);
```

Here you can see that you can safely pass the pointer like this:

```
int t = atoi(&x);
++x;
```

Or preferably:

```
int t = atoi(&x++);
```

Comment: I retyped my code on stackoverflow, in my code I have better variables names but that computer is not on me ;)